# Why C++ msgpack-c adds number 13 (0x0D) before number 10 (0x0A), but C# MessagePack-CSharp does not?

Tags: c#, c++, msgpack, binary-serialization

I was trying to use MessagePack to serialize integers from 0 to 127 in C++ and in C# on Windows, but the results are not the same. msgpack-c inserts 0x0D between 0x09 and 0x0A, but MessagePack-CSharp does not. Why is that?

OS: Windows 10

IDE: Visual Studio 2019

C#

library:

https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp

code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("CSharp.msgpack", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }

            MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, list);
        }
    }
}
```

result:

[image: CSharp]

C++

library:

https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c

code:

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::ofstream OutputFileStream;

    std::vector<int> list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    {
        list.push_back(i);
    }

    OutputFileStream.open("Cpp.msgpack");

    msgpack::pack(OutputFileStream, list);

    OutputFileStream.close();
}
```

result:

[image: Cpp]

Comment: That is a carriage return.

Comment: But if I have a list of 128 integers serialized in a binary file, the result should be the same, should it not?

Comment: Is the carriage return discarded when you deserialize?

Comment: I am trying to serialize in C++ and deserialze in C#

Comment: Oh.  Well my guess is that the two pieces of software aren't guaranteed to be compatible with each other.

Comment: If you are serialising into a binary file, then you need to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Good catch, but why would a text stream assume something about the size of your lines?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the perennial Unix vs MS-Windows line-ending issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you open the file in c++ in text mode then every `\n` (ASCII 10) will have `\r` (ASCII 13) prepended if it doesn’t exist on Windows. You need to open the file in binary mode for this to not happen.

```
OutputFileStream.open("Cpp.msgpack", std::ofstream::binary);
```